# $(window).scroll(function() {...}) not loading in Bootstrap v3.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use the `$(window).scroll` function in my [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xCVsWXFE7EqNlkdUJUc?p=preview) example to change a variable when the user scrolls the window:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      document.getElementById('myResults').innerHTML = $(window).scrollTop();
  });
});
```

The desired behavior is that `#myResults` will change from its default html value and update to the current `$(window).scrollTop();` value each time any scrolling occurs.

But I can't get it to work. I don't believe it's the Angular routing module causing the problem because I created [a second example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vjbxQrfKapwEJm4ealwi?p=preview) where the `#myResults` element is rendered as part of a view and it still works OK. My primary example is rendered through a view but not working... What's different in the first example? How can I get the first example to work please?

Comment: have you tried this in production? It may just break because of what window is actual referencing.

Comment: @dbarnes: Yes. Have been developing it on a local server when I encountered this problem. Then moved it to Plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st example, the `window` isn't the object that the scrollbar is applied to.

That instead is the following `<div>`:

```
<div id="targetDiv" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope">
```

Which is [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to fill the viewport and allows scrolling when its content [overflows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) its dimensions:

```
// Main Panel Styling (line 229 of main.less)

#targetDiv{
    /* ... */

    position: absolute;
    top:      0;
    bottom:   0;
    left:     0;
    right:    0;
    overflow: auto;

    /* ... */
}
```

You'll have to reference this element for both the event and current value to react to its content being scrolled:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#targetDiv').scroll(function(){
    document.getElementById('myResults').innerHTML = $('#targetDiv').scrollTop();
  });
});
```